# android studio 2.0 ndk С++ 11 Error:(15, 5) error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, android-studio, c++11, android-ndk, jni

Не получается добавить поддержку C++ 11-ой версии в Android studio 2.0. Появилась нужда использовать библиотеки thread и mutex. Не могу создать объект типа thread постоянно вылезает ошибка:

```
Error:(15, 5) error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
```

файл build.grade app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

  model {
  android {
      compileSdkVersion = 23
      buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

      defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId  = "com.example.a1.enetndktest"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

    }
}

android.ndk {
    moduleName = "EnetTest"
    stl = "gnustl_shared"
    cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
   cppFlags.add("-Wall")
   cppFlags.add("-g")
    cppFlags.add("-libstdc++")
    cppFlags.add("-lsupc++")
    cppFlags.add("-pthread")
   cppFlags.add("-frtti")
    cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
     cppFlags.add("-DANDROID")
    ldLibs.addAll(["android", "dl", "atomic", "log", "EGL", "GLESv2", "z"])

}

android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
    }
}
android.productFlavors {
    create("arm") {
        ndk.with{
            abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
    }
    create("armv7") {
        ndk.with {
            abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")



        }
    }
}
// Our workaround
compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: [$/*.jar/$])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1"
}
```

файл build.grade project

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Файл кода C++

```
  #include <jni.h>
 #include "TestThreadClass.h"



  JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_clib_ClibInt_enetinit(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
     TestThreadClass t;
      t.threadFunction();

      return 10;
   }
```

Заголовочный файл TestThreadClass.h

```
 #ifndef ENETNDKTEST2_TESTTHREADCLASS_H
 #define ENETNDKTEST2_TESTTHREADCLASS_H
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

 class TestThreadClass {
 public:
   void threadFunction();
 };


 #endif //ENETNDKTEST2_TESTTHREADCLASS_H
```

Файл TestThreadClass.cpp

```
#include "TestThreadClass.h"

 void threadFunction1() {
   int i = 0;
   while (i < 100000) {
    i++;
   }
  }

 void TestThreadClass::threadFunction(){
    thread t(threadFunction1);
    t.join();
  }
```

Вызов C++ функции из java

```
package clib;

public class ClibInt {
 static {
    System.loadLibrary("EnetTest");
   }
   public native int enetinit();
}
```

Comment: А откуда информация, что там должен быть именно `thread`**`.h`**?

Comment: в стандарте С++11 есть такая библиотека заголовочный файл которой thread.h))если инклудить все библиотеки без h будет ошибка

Comment: В стандартной библиотеке С++11 нет такого заголовочного файла. [А вот `thread` есть.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/thread).

Comment: проинклюдил #include <thread> ничего не изменилось))

Comment: Это нормально. Значит, неверный заголовочный файл это лишь одна из многих имеющихся у вас проблем.

Comment: Каких проблем на пример??

Comment: Как файл может быть неверным если на эклипсе прописав -std=c++11 он нормально инклудиться??

Comment: Неправильные настройки сборки, вероятнее всего. [Вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21386866/2076787), например, советуют ещё заменить `srlport_shared` на `gnustl_shared`.

Comment: В Android studio 2.0 отсутствует файл настроек Application.mk и Android .mk там все настройки сборки прописываются в build.grade. Как прописать в Android.mk настройки сборки я знаю. А вот с build.grade встрял намертво.

Comment: А я и не сказал, в каком файле это сделать. У вас означенное значение указано в вопросе :)

Comment: Замена на gnustl_shared не сработала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените компилятор на clang с рантаймом c++_static:

```
toolchain = "clang"
stl = 'c++_static'
```

Либо скачайте старую версию NDK (версию 11c) с основного сайта: [NDK Downloads](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html?hl=ru)

В NDK версии 12, приходящей вместе с android studio, есть какие-то проблемы с std::thread и gnustl

Вот пример gradle-файла проекта с std::thread: [github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/choreographer-30fps/app/build.gradle](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master/choreographer-30fps/app/build.gradle)

Comment: Error:Unable to load class 'org.gradle.nativeplatform.internal.DefaultBuildType_Decorated'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Android studio просто кошмар(( в эклипсе всё гораздо проще

Comment: Создал новый проект. Скачал NDK 11c и сделал gradle-файл как в примере и заработало. Спасибо огромное))